# st link utility cannot stay connected to the device

Tags: stm32f4

So, I'm trying to connect to a custom board using ST-Link. My board uses STM32 Microcontroller and I use ST link utility software to see if I can connect to it.

Right now, If I press connect on utility software and press reset on my board at the same time, the connection is successful. But as soon as I remove my finger from the reset button the connection to the device is lost. Is this expected? And how can I make it stay connected without me keeping the reset button pressed!

Also, assuming I keep pressing it, the utility software gives me an internal command error when I try to erase chip. this happens when I try to program the chip as well.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So the way to resolve the issue was to pull-up the NRST pin on the board and st link and disconnect it after pressing the reset button.

I still have not found a solution for erasing the chip but I believe the flash is protected. When I try to change the Option Bytes in st link utility, it disconnects from the board saying:
Could not set Option bytes!
Please reset the target and retry!

And then disconnects from the device.

Any clues how I can change the options bytes? That might actually solve the problem!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By my experience all of such this problems come from bad assembling one way that may help you to find out first put a light in the back of your PCB right under your micro-controller and see if any pin is outside of footprint if it is aligned correctly,gently press your micro to the PCB and and test if it is disconnecting if it solves your problem then some of pins are not soldered correctly